# Splitting a html text into characters and html tags (with PHP & MySQL)

Tags: php, html-parsing

I want to store a html text into database as splitted to individual characters. Since,  the text is long and the process is frequence, performance is of particular importance. Thus, I need to find an efficient way to conudct this in `PHP` without overload of building multiple arrays.

Of course, the purpose is simple text with a few markup html tags, without nested nodes. It can be considered for BBCode or something like that. I just want to have this possibility to skip some tags in this split process.

**Example:**

```
$html='This <i>is</i> a <strong>test</test>';
```

This string should be stored in `mysql` database as

```
id  character  html_tag
1    T
2    h
3    i
4    s
5
6    i          italic
7    s          italic
8
9    a
10
11   t          strong
12   e          strong
13   s          strong
14   t          strong
15   !
```

How to capture the individual characters without corresponding html tags?

Comment: How do you plan on storing `<strong>nested <em>tags</em> </strong>`? But if performance & correctness is an issue, go with `xmlreader`.

Comment: @Wrikken 1. If finding a practical solution, it can be somehow extended to child nodes too, 2. I am talking about simple html text (consider even bbcodes), otherwise, it is impossible to do this with nested `DIV`s.

Comment: What you are doing is parsing HTML.  You need to use an HTML parser to do this.  See http://htmlparsing.com/php.html for examples and pointers to libraries.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php

Comment: @AndyLester no it is no parsing HTML, as I edited the question, it can be for a case other than HTML. It is just a process to skip some tags during split process.

Comment: @AndyLester Regarding the tags, yes it is connected with `mysql`, as this process can even be done by `mysql` functions, since the target is to be stored in database. It is just easier to do this in PHP, but no obligation.

Comment: There is no generic way to parse both BBCode and HTML.  There is a BBCode parser built in to PHP, however. http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php

Comment: @AndyLester I am aware of PHP functions. It is matter of characters only. We can `str_split` and in a `foreach` loop check for reaching any pre-defined tag. I just wanted to know if there is a better implemention.

Answer (score 2):

Parse Html with fast XMLReader.

This code will also work with nested tags, `$tags` variable is stack of tags. Here I always echo the most nested tag, the last one in stack.

```
$html='This <i>is</i> a <strong>test</strong>!';

$reader=new XMLReader();
$reader->XML('<root>'.$html.'</root>');
// skip root node
$reader->read();
$tags=array('');
while($reader->read())
    switch($reader->nodeType)
    {
        case $reader::ELEMENT:
            $tags[]=$reader->name;
            break;
        case $reader::END_ELEMENT;
            array_pop($tags);
            break;
        default:
            for($i=0;$i<strlen($reader->value);$i++)
                // your insert sql here
                echo "<br/>'".$reader->value[$i]."' ".end($tags);
    }
```

Also, because speed is crucial, consider buffering inserts into string and running them as a batch:

```
INSERT INTO tname (character,html_tag) VALUES('T',''),('h','');
```